# How to change persistance model for angular-xeditable?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I'm using http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ and looking at their jsfiddle for tables: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/

```
$scope.saveUser = function(data, id) {
  //$scope.user not updated yet
  angular.extend(data, {id: id});
  return $http.post('/saveUser', data);
};
```

I want to change the fact that the local model is only persisted/updated after a save to the remote service succeeds.

1) How can I do that?

2) Also as an aside is it possible to apply `onbeforesave` to dropdowns/select?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can update after the request returns the promise.

```
$scope.saveUser = function(data,id){
     angular.extend(data, {id: id});
     $http.post('/saveUser', data)
       .then(
          //callback function for success save to server
          function(response){
             //do any of your update here
             $scope.item = data.item;
          },
          //else handle your error here
          function(error){
          console.log(error)
          }
       );
```

Comment: Turns out there is `onaftersave` so I used that